# String stream variable length of inputs from terminal, what is the best way to implement

Tags: c++, user-input, stringstream

I am working on an assignment where we are asked to fill a AVL tree with values.

The code needs to take a line form the terminal and perform additions to the tree as well as deletions. then finally print the AVL tree in order.

A string from the terminal would look like this

```
A3 A5 A6 D5 D6 print
```

The string can be any length 1 - 100 inputs long.

My question is what is the best way to implement a terminal reader function that will efficiently and effectively record and the input values and even initialise the input, delete and print functions?

I am familliar with string stream and the sstream library, but am struggling to find a nice solution to this problem.

Some pseudo code for a function I am envisioning would look something like this.

```
void stringReader(string sentence){
    string word;
    stringstream instring(input);

    instring >> word;//word should be a single input ie: "A3" or "D6" 
                     //in the 0th position of the string stream.

    if (word == "print"){
        printAVL(node* treeroot);
        return; 
    }else{
        if(statement to determine if A or D){
              //perform deletion or addition;
        }
    }
    input.removeFirstWord()//some magic function I am yet to find that removes the first input 
                           //and allows me to do this recursively.
    stringReader(input);

}

int main(){
    string input; 
    getline(cin, input);//the raw input line from terminal ie;"A3 A5 A6 D5 D6 print"
    stringReader(input);
}
```

I am not 100% committed to a recursive method nor am I heart-set on using the sstream library any ideas or methods are much appreciated.

EDIT - using a while loop and appending strings to a vector is another idea I'm working on.

Thanks for your help

PS - The assignment is to judge our ability to write a AVL tree program, handling of inputs is not marked. I just want a nice method to use and a chance to develop my skills further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a recursive function and also not some magic "removeFirstWord" function.

If you have data in a `std::istringstream` and you extract them with the >> operator, then the data is already "gone", You will not read it again. The internal mechanisms of the `stream` will advance some internal pointer. (This is a very simplified explanation).

The solution is, to extract all words in the `std::istringstream` with a simple while loop. The extraction statement `instring >> word` returns a reference to the original `std::istringstream`, in this case to "instring". And there is an override of the `bool` operator for `streams`, which indicates, if the `fail` bit of the stream is set or not. And, this is also set, when the stream is "emptied" completely (EOF).

So, with the command

```
while (instring >> word) {
```

You will read all words from the "instring".

Then you can check for the valid commands and perform the necessary operations.

You can see this in the below example. Please note: I did not implement an AVL tree. I made a mock using a `std::set`. You need to implement the AVL tree by yourself.

Example (one of many possible solutions):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>

// A Pseudo AVL. It is a std::set and a Red Black tree
struct PretendToBeAnAVLtree {

    // Data container
    std::set<int> data{};

    // Add function
    void addValue(int value) {
        auto result = data.insert(value);
        if (!result.second) std::cerr << "\n*** Error Add: Value " << value << " is already in tree\n";
    };
    // Delete function
    void deleteValue(int value) {
        auto it = data.find(value);
        if (it == data.end())
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error Delete: Value " << value << " is not in tree\n";
        else
            data.erase(it);
    }
    // Print function
    void print() {
        for (const int i : data) std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
};

// Replace PretendToBeAnAVLtree with your implementation of a real AVL tree
using AVL = PretendToBeAnAVLtree;

// Read some string and execute the commands in the input string
void processInputData(const std::string& input, AVL& avl) {

    // Some debug output
    std::cout << "\nInput data: " << input << "\n";

    // Put the input string into an istringstream for easier word extraction
    std::istringstream instring(input);

    // Now read all words from the istringstream and and consume them
    std::string word{};
    while (instring >> word) {

        // Depending on the command in the word
        // Check for print command
        if (word == "print") {
            avl.print(); 
        } // Check for add command
        else if (word[0] == 'A') {
            try { 
                // Convert string starting at position 1 of the word to an integer
                int value = std::stoi(word.substr(1));
                // Add the value to the tree
                avl.addValue(value); }
            // In case of conversion error 
            catch (...) { std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid add command '" << word << "' in input data\n"; }
        } // Check for Delete
        else if (word[0] == 'D') {
            try {
                // Convert string starting at position 1 of the word to an integer
                int value = std::stoi(word.substr(1));
                // Delete the value from the tree
                avl.deleteValue(value);
            }
            // In case of conversion error 
            catch (...) { std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid delete command '" << word << "' in input data\n"; }
        }
        else {
            // In case of a totaly unknown command
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid command '" << word << "' in input data\n";
        }
    }
}

// Driver code
int main() {

    // The AVL
    AVL avl;

    // Some test commands
    processInputData("A3 A5 A6 D5 D6 print", avl);
    processInputData("A1 A2 A4 A5 print A6 A7 A8 A9 print", avl);
    processInputData("A3 A100 print", avl);
    processInputData("D3 D4 D555 print", avl);
    processInputData("A200 X999 A300 print", avl);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, your answer helped me streamline my stringReader() a lot. The idea of calling the input and delete functions form inside the while-loop meant I didn't need to double or even triple handle data, seems like an obvious strategy now. Thanks for the help :)